# JavaScript associate arrays comparing

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I suppose that I have three arrays:

```
dict['tag'] = 'INPUT';
dict['type'] = 'checkbox';
dict['name'] = 'remember'

dict2['tag'] = 'INPUT2';
dict2['type'] = 'checkbox';
dict2['name'] = 'remember';

dict3['type'] = 'checkboxEdit';
dict3['name'] = 'remember'
dict3['tag'] = 'INPUT3';
```

Now what I want to achieve is that I want know how many elements of arrays are equal even when arrays are not sorted, so for instance

```
function(dict, dict2) return 2 //cause input values are not the same
function(dict, dict3) return 1 //cause name values are the same
function(dict2, dict3) return 1 //cause name values are the same
```

What is the most effective way to achieve this ? Also data structure can be changed so if there is something better, let me know.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays." It has *objects*. (This will help with your searches.)

Comment: *"Also data structure can be changed so if there is something better, let me know."* You'd probably be better off with an array of objects, e.g. `[{tag: 'INPUT', type: 'checkbox', name: 'remember'}, {'tag: 'INPUT2', 'type': 'checkbox', name: 'remember'}, ...]` (What's an "INPUT2"?)

Comment: Input2 is not valid tag, sry for this :), but lets suppose it is div :)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple realy..

```js
var dict = {}, dict2 = {}, dict3 = {};

dict['tag'] = 'INPUT';
dict['type'] = 'checkbox';
dict['name'] = 'remember'

dict2['tag'] = 'INPUT2';
dict2['type'] = 'checkbox';
dict2['name'] = 'remember';

dict3['type'] = 'checkboxEdit';
dict3['name'] = 'remember'
dict3['tag'] = 'INPUT3';

function compare(d1, d2) {
  var count = 0;
  Object.keys(d1).forEach(function (k) {
      if(d1[k] === d2[k]) count++;
  });
  return count;
}

alert(compare(dict, dict2));
alert(compare(dict, dict3));
alert(compare(dict2, dict3));
```